# Iterating on array gives the wrong result

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, iteration

I am currently making a task in which I have an array of kids in range of(1,n) and they are playing a box game where first it starts from left to right to choose the kid that looses, so for example if we have 5 kids and the amount of moves is 3 then it iterates on the array 0 1 2 3 so the kid number 4 looses, then the kid that looses has to give the box to the kid that gave him the box so in this case kid nr 3 and in the next iteration it needs to change direction from right to left and change the direction on each iteration.

```
numberOfKids = int(input())
kidsArray = list(range(1, numberOfKids+1))
boxesArray = [i for i in range(numberOfKids)]
currentIndex = 0
direction = 1
print(kidsArray)
for i in range(numberOfKids-1):
    moves = int(input())
    removeIndex = (currentIndex + moves*direction) % len(kidsArray)
    removeElement = kidsArray[removeIndex]
    boxesElement = boxesArray[removeIndex]
    kidsArray.remove(removeElement)
    boxesArray.remove(boxesElement)
    if direction == 1:
        currentIndex = removeIndex % len(kidsArray)
    else:
        currentIndex = (removeIndex-1) % len(kidsArray)
    if direction == 1:
        direction = direction * -1
    else:
        direction = 1
    print(kidsArray)

print(kidsArray[0])
```

This is my current code and the problem is that for `moves=2` the result is `[1,3,5]` but should be `[2,3,5]`, I know the problem is with iteration but I do not know how to fix it.
Here is an explanation for example 5 3 2 5 1:
Explanation of the example: Let's use bold to mark the location of the box. At first he receives
hot box always first child: `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Music stops after three passes
so the fourth child is out: `[1,2,3,5]`. Now the box goes two to the left, it falls off
first child: `[2,3,5]`. Next - cyclically - five times to the right - the fifth one is eliminated: `[2,3]`. And once
to the left - only the third child is left: `[3]`.